# woocommerce Error 500 when I want to print 200 bills

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new with wordpress and my problem is this :

When I use woocommerce for printing 200 bills, it returns an error 500. The printing works when I print 20 but if I want more, it stops working.

I don't know how I can fix it..

Thank you for you help

Comment: Check your server settings.

Comment: Check your `php.ini` settings on the server. Increase memory settings and/or timeout limit. See your webserver error log for the reason of the 500.

Comment: My wp is already online because  had problem to put it in local (phmyadmin problems). Where can I find the php.ini from the wp with FileZilla?

Comment: We can't tell you that, it depends on the actual setup. If you call `phpinfo()`, it will tell you which php.ini file was actually used. Whether you will be allowed to make changes in there, is another question though. But both `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` are changeable `PHP_INI_ALL`, so you could set them using `ini_set` directly from within code as well.